# Can java's assert statement allow you to specify a message?

Tags: java, assert

Seems likes it might be useful to have the assert display a message when an assertion fails.

Currently an `AssertionError` gets thrown, can you specify a custom message for it?

Can you show an example mechanism for doing this (other than creating your own exception type and throwing it)?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You certainly can:

```
assert x > 0 : "x must be greater than zero, but x = " + x;
```

See [Programming with Assertions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) for more information.

Answer (score 22):

```
assert (condition) : "some message";
```

I'd recommend putting the conditional in brackets

```
assert (y > x): "y is too small. y = " + y;
```

Imagine if you came across code like this...

```
assert isTrue() ? true : false : "some message";
```

Don't forget this has nothing to do with asserts you'd write in JUnit.

Comment: There is no point in wrapping every expression in brackets just because a ternary would otherwise be slightly confusing. If you happen to have a ternary expression as your assertion, you can wrap that. (Although I would argue that if you have a ternary expression as your assertion, you have probably messed up & at the very least you should extract the expression into a named method call for clarity.)

Answer (score 12):

It absolutely does:

```
assert importantVar != null : "The important var was null!";
```

This will add "The important var was null" to the exception that is thrown.

Answer (score 8):

If you use

```
assert Expression1 : Expression2 ;
```

Expression2 is used as a detail message for the AssertionError.

Comment: Just adding that AssertionError is thrown if Expression1 is false.